# Torres de hanoi

Tags: c

He estado tratando de hacer mi programa de **torres de hanoi**, que permita al usuario seleccionar el movimiento que hará, en principio funciona bien, pero conforma avanza ya no permite hacer los cambios, creo que no estoy usando correctamente los contadores de cada torre, lo estoy tratando de hacer con punteros,pero es la primera vez que trabajo con ellos, por lo que soy muy novato, no se si los estoy implementando correctamente.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct torre
{
    int disco[5];
} typedef torre;

torre *t1,*t2,*t3;
int *at1, *at2, *at3;
int main()
{
    int i,j,k=0,ban=0;
    system("clear");
    t1=(torre *)malloc(sizeof(torre));
    t2=(torre *)malloc(sizeof(torre));
    t3=(torre *)malloc(sizeof(torre));
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        t1->disco[i]=k+1;
        t2->disco[i]=0;
        t3->disco[i]=0;
        k++;
    }
    while (ban==0)
    {
        head();
        scanf("%d",&j);
        switch (j)
        {

        case 1:
            head();
            t1a2();
            break;
        case 2:
            head();
            t2a1();
            break;
        case 3:
            head();
            t2a3();
            break;
        case 4:
            head();
            t3a2();
            break;
        case 5:
            ban=1;
            printf("Adios\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("\E[1;31mSelecciona una opcion valida\E[00m");

        }
    }

}
head()
{
    system("clear");
    printf("\n\E[1;34m Bienvenido al juego\n TORRES DE HANOI\n 5 Discos\E[00m\n\n\E[1;33mReglas\n*Sólo se puede mover un disco cada vez\n*Un disco de mayor tamaño no puede descansar sobre uno más pequeño\n*Sólo puedes desplazar el disco que se encuentre arriba\E[00m\n\n");
    printf("Selecciona un opcion: \n1:T1->T2\n2:T2->T1\n3:T2->T3\n4:T3->T2\n5: Salir\n");
    imprime();
}

nope()
{
    system("clear");
    printf("\E[1;31mMovimiento invalido..Lee bien las reglas\E[00m");
}

imprime()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("  |%d|\t  |%d|\t  |%d|\n",t1->disco[i],t2->disco[i],t3->disco[i]);
    }
    printf("Torre 1\tTorre 2\tTorre 3\n");
}
int d1=0,d2=4,d3=4;


t1a2()
{
    at1=&t1->disco[d1];
    at2=&t2->disco[d2];

    if(*at2==0)
    {
        *at2=*at1;
        *at1=0;
        d1++;
        at1=&t1->disco[d1];
    }
    if (*at2!=0 && *at1!=0 && *at2>*at1)
    {
        at2=&t2->disco[d2];
        *at2=*at1;
        *at1=0;
    }
    else
    {
        nope();
    }
    printf("d1 %d,d2 %d",d1,d2);
}

t2a1()
{
    at1=&t1->disco[d1];
    at2=&t2->disco[d2];
    if(*at1==0)
    {
        *at1=*at2;
        *at2=0;
        d2++;
    }
    if (*at1!=0 && *at2!=0 && *at2<*at1)
    {
        d1--;
        at1=&t1->disco[d1];
        *at1=*at2;
        *at2=0;
    }
    else
    {
        nope();
    }
    printf("d1 %d,d2 %d",d1,d2);
}

t2a3()
{
    at2=&t2->disco[d2];
    at3=&t3->disco[d3];
    if(*at3==0)
    {
        *at3=*at2;
        *at2=0;
    }
    if (*at3>*at2 && *at2!=0 && *at3>*at2)
    {
        d2--;
        at2=&t2->disco[d2];
        *at3=*at2;
        *at2=0;
    }
    else
    {
        nope();
    }
    printf("d2 %d,d3 %d",d2,d3);
}

t3a2()
{
    at2=&t2->disco[d2];
    at3=&t3->disco[d3];
    if(*at2==0)
    {
        *at2=*at3;
        *at3=0;
    }
    if (*at2!=0 && *at3!=0 && *at3<*at2)
    {
        d2--;
        at2=&t2->disco[d2];
        *at2=*at3;
        *at3=0;
    }
    else
    {
        nope();
    }
    printf("d2 %d,d3 %d",d2,d3);
}
```

Comment: Si se me permite una(s) sugerencia(s): sigue el principio DRY (o [No Te Repitas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_te_repitas)): muchas de las funciones son iguales (sólo varían las variables que representan las torres) y podrían simplificarse pasando las torres como parámetros (así también dejarían de ser variables globales, que es otro no-no). Eso reduciría el código considerablemente y lo haría mucho más fácil de mantener y depurar (y te permitiría hacer t1a3 y t3a1 sin ningún cambio adicional)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar esto, hay que arreglar porque lo hice en 10 minutos y hay errores pero creo que está más sencillo para ti cambiarlo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_TOWERS 3
#define MAX_TOWERS_SIZE 5

struct torre
{
    char name;
    int disco[MAX_TOWERS_SIZE];
    int count;
} typedef torre;

torre *list_towers[MAX_TOWERS];

void head();
void imprime();


void init_towers()
{ 
    int i=0, j = 0;
    char identificador = 'a';

    for(int i=0;i<MAX_TOWERS ; i++)
    {
     list_towers[i]= (torre *)malloc(sizeof(torre));
     list_towers[i]->name = identificador++; //a > b > c > d ...

       int k = MAX_TOWERS_SIZE;
       for(j=0; j<MAX_TOWERS_SIZE; j++)
        {
            if(list_towers[i]->name=='a')
            {           
                list_towers[i]->disco[j]=k--;
                list_towers[i]->count = MAX_TOWERS_SIZE;
            }
            else
            {
                list_towers[i]->disco[j]=0;
                list_towers[i]->count = 0;
            }
        }

        /*printf("%c [0]%i [1]%i [2]%i [3]%i [4]%i qtd[%i]\n"  , list_towers[i]->name
                                        ,list_towers[i]->disco[0]
                                        ,list_towers[i]->disco[1]
                                        ,list_towers[i]->disco[2]
                                        ,list_towers[i]->disco[3]
                                        ,list_towers[i]->disco[4]
                                        ,list_towers[i]->count );*/

    }   
}

void move(char from, char to)
{
    torre *p_to,*p_from;
    printf("\nMoving from %c to %c\n", from, to);  

    for(int i=0;i<MAX_TOWERS ; i++)
    {
       if(list_towers[i]->name==to)
       {
         p_to = list_towers[i];
       }

       if(list_towers[i]->name==from)
       {
         p_from = list_towers[i];
       }       
    }    

       if(p_from->count==0)
       {
         printf("\nImpossible porque no existe elementos\n");   
         return;
       }

       if(p_to->count==MAX_TOWERS_SIZE)
       {
         printf("\nImpossible porque no esta lleno\n");   
         return;
       }

       //cambiando se menor o valor "to" igual a cero (vacia)
       if((p_to->disco[p_to->count] < p_from->disco[p_from->count]) || (p_to->count == 0))
       {    
           p_to->disco[p_to->count] = p_from->disco[(p_from->count)-1];
           p_from->disco[(p_from->count)-1] = 0;
           p_from->count--;
           p_to->count++;        
       }
       else
       {
         printf("\nImpossible porque el elemento necesita ser menor\n");   
         return;
       }

       imprime();   

} 

void head()
{
    system("clear");
    printf("\n\E[1;34m Bienvenido al juego\n TORRES DE HANOI\n 5 Discos\E[00m\n\n\E[1;33mReglas\n*Sólo se puede mover un disco cada vez\n*Un disco de mayor tamaño no puede descansar sobre uno más pequeño\n*Sólo puedes desplazar el disco que se encuentre arriba\E[00m\n\n");
    printf("Selecciona un opcion: \n1:T1->T2\n2:T2->T1\n3:T2->T3\n4:T3->T2\n5: T1->T3\n6: Salir\n");
    imprime();
}

void imprime()
{
    int i;
    for(i=(MAX_TOWERS_SIZE-1); i>=0; i--)
    {
        printf("  |%d|\t  |%d|\t  |%d|\n",list_towers[0]->disco[i],list_towers[1]->disco[i],list_towers[2]->disco[i]);
    }
    printf("Torre 1\tTorre 2\tTorre 3\n");
}

int main()
{
    int i,j,k=0,ban=0;

    init_towers();

    //system("clear");
    imprime();

    move('a','b');
    move('a','b');
    move('a','c');
    move('b','c');
    move('c','a');

   // imprime();
}
```